# PHP - If/Else... statement - Syntax Differences

Tags: php, if-statement

PHP noob here. A company I do work for has an if/else statement set up like this:

```
{if product_type != ""} {product_type} {if:else}No Product Type{/if}
```

Other research I do though provides a format such as the following:

```
<?php if ($bodyID==='home') { ?>
    <h1>I am home!</h1>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>I'm not home!</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Is there a specific reason for the differences in syntax, or is that just how the previous developer wrote it?

Comment: The second is PHP the first is not.  Maybe a template engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is not php, it is a template engine,  possibly https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html . The second one is valid php code.

Comment: This comment is the first thing I've found that actually references this syntax. Thank you so much Alvaro!

Answer (score 0):

If-Else syntax allow you to bind the evaluation to the first if statement.  This is pseudo-code, not PHP:

```
If (Johnny > 18){ Johnny is a minor} else if (Johnny < 65) { Johnny is an adult} else {Johnny is eligible for Social Security}
```

It is possible from the question you asked, that the second if condition is nested in the if-else statement of the first.

```
If (x > 0){ do Y}
Else{
       If(x < 100){do Z}
       Else {do A}
}
```